# Financial Contagion (Epidemic spread) Model Meets Problem

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx, finance

Recently I want to rebuild the financial contagion model in the paper: [Contagion in Financial Networks](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1577043) by Prasanna Gai.
Now I am stuck in the first figure:

[image: first figure] (figure 3 actually).

### What I Did

I used Python and `networkx`.

- First, build the ER network with 1000 nodes, and the probability depends on which average degree I want to simulate. For example, if I want to simulate the average degree at 3, then the probability of generating ER network is 3/(1000-1) where 1000 is the network size.
- Then for each node, I find how many nodes point towards it and count, to calculate the AiIB (weights). If node 1 has 3 nodes point towards it, then the weights on these edges are AiIB (0.2 in paper) / 3 (number of neighbours).
- To simulate contagion, first randomly chose one node to remove all its assets. then it cannot pay back the liabilities to its neighbours if the liability is more than the capital buffer (Ki, 0.04 in the paper). For those banks received liabilities from more than one banks, even each link's weight is less than the Ki, if the sum of these liabilities is more than Ki it still is considered as bankrupt. The model is just like epidemic spread where the new bankrupt banks will influence the new batch of banks, ended at no more banks are bankrupted in this system.
- As contagion is defined as more than 5% of the banks bankrupt in this network ( 50 in this case).
- To plot the figure, each average degree needs to test 100 times:

  - probability = number of contagion happened / simulation times 100 here
  - extent = [under the case of happening contagion] sum of the fraction of bankrupt banks/number of contagion happened.

The raw code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rewove/finance_contagion). By running er_100.py you can get the figure of mine like this:

[image: figure 2]

If you have any trouble of the code please let me know. (the code needs at least 1 hours to run on the GCP with 8 vCPU...)

I also tried the network with 60 nodes here is it looks like: [image: 60 nodes]

it has a little similar shape with figure 1. But this still not good and the small network is not what I want.

I don't know what problems with my code. In my view, I have considered everywhere and it should get similar results. I even started to question the authority of the paper...

If you have any ideas please help me with this.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I asked this dumb question here but I am really have no idea with this assignment. I tried everything I cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "hard" question to answer.

I still do not find any clue to the code. Then I rewrite the code in R and run it, here is the draft figure I got:

[image: raw figure]

As you can see now the figure is just the one in the paper. But the **algorithm and the structure** were **totally the same** with I wrote it in Python.

Maybe this is a case that shows **Python just can't do**.
If anyone feels interesting of this question, want to divide more among the difference between Python and R, this is a great example. And I am very happy to offer any helps.

By the way the model code in R is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/Rewove/financial-contagion-in-R) and it still under update.

For those who spent time on reading my description, Thanks for your time.

update:

I am also can't believe this because in my view the code is doing count and calculate that's simple. I print out very thing at every step and check every node, from 10 nodes small network to 1000 nodes network, the log file reached over 50G. All looks normal and the number (bankrupt one) just not reach the threshold. Not like in R, with totally the same structure, the results is just `same` with the paper.

I really don't know why and have no idea.

Comment: It's much more likely that there is a typo somewhere in your Python code than that this is something Python can't do.

Comment: @Joel Hi, I understand but the code has been checked under three person and debug for 2 weeks, we even checked if the `random` function not that random .... I only spent  2 hours to rewrite the code in R to get that results. All the source code is available on GitHub if you don't mind and feels it is interesting worth a further invest, happy to help.